# Error reading Avro file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

I'm trying to read an avro file into Python, and the following code works on OSX and linux box but breaks on a Windows:

```
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("my_file.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for line in reader:
    print(line)
    break
```

Why do I get the following error on Windows only?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\datafile.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._read_header()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\datafile.py", line 463, in _read_header
    META_SCHEMA, META_SCHEMA, self.raw_decoder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 526, in read_data
    return self.read_record(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 726, in read_record
    field_val = self.read_data(field.type, readers_field.type, decoder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 522, in read_data
    return self.read_map(writer_schema, reader_schema, decoder)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 657, in read_map
    key = decoder.read_utf8()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 249, in read_utf8
    input_bytes = self.read_bytes()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 241, in read_bytes
    assert (nbytes >= 0), nbytes
AssertionError: -51
```

I get the following error while using `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar` on windows (using `avro-tools-1.8.2.jar` on mac works):

```
PS D:\Temp> java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson my_file.avro
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a data file.
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:105)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.<init>(DataFileStream.java:84)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileReadTool.run(DataFileReadTool.java:71)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:87)
        at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue that you should raise on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO

Comment: Were you able to resolve this or submit a bug report. Looks like an OS specific issue. I also encountered a similar issue while trying to read an avro file created on Windows using C# and reading it on Mac/Linux using Python3